# How to have a if statment inside if

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have two rank in my forum Admin = 1 and User = 0 Then this code is doing so the admin get red name.

```
 if($info['rank'] == 1) { $x= "<a class='admin'>".$last_user."</a>"; 
            } else { $x= "<a class='user'>".$last_user."</a>"; }
```

But everyone is getting red name..

Comment: Can you show the whole code, without interrupting it?

Comment: What you need is done with PHP it is matter of unclosed { by order. Check your code again. as a suggestion use an IDE with code highligh.

Comment: Read http://whathaveyoutried.com before asking other questions :)

Comment: .... Im posting it here because i dont know how to fix it not because im lazy.. @VladPreda

Comment: I did not get any answer on that question in 2-3 hours so im asking again if some can see what im doing worng @EricLeschinski

Comment: The only thing I can think of it's you are probably did not changed the color in your class 'user'.

Comment: I did `.user {
 font-weight:900;
 color: #0088cc;
 text-decoration: none !important;
}`

Comment: If you want to bump your question, provide status and progress updates resulting from your own continued efforts to answer the original question yourself.  If you acquire more than 75 reputation, you can offer bounty on your own question.  Please Read this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-do-i-get-attention-for-old-unanswered-questions

Comment: I just checked your code and it seems to be working.

Comment: Same here, works fine http://phpfiddle.org/api/run/35q-vvu

Comment: Can i see the code @Malcolm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the $x where you want to wish.

```
<?PHP 
if (mysql_num_rows($res) > 0) {
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {


        if($info[rank] == 1) { $x= "<div class='admin'>".$last_user."</div>"; } else { $x="<div>".$last_user."</div>"; }

        $tid = $row['id'];
        $cid = $row['category_id'];
        $title = $row['topic_title'];
        $views = $row['topic_views'];
        $date = $row['topic_date'];
        $creator = $row['topic_creator'];
        if ($row['topic_last_user']== "") { $last_user = getusername($row['topic_creator']); } else { $last_user = getusername($row['topic_last_user']); }
        if ($row['topic_last_user']== "") { $last2_user = 'Started by'; } else { $last2_user = 'Most recent by'; }
        $topics .="
        <li class='category'><div class='left_cat'>
        <a class='underline' href='view_topic.php?cid=".$cid."&tid=".$tid."'>
        <div class='title'><i class='icon-comment'></i>&nbsp;".$title."</div></a>
        <div class='info'><i class='icon-comments icon-1'></i>&nbsp;".topicreplies($cid, $tid)." Comments&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;<i class='icon-user icon-1'>
        &nbsp;</i>".$last2_user."&nbsp;&nbsp; 

        $x

        &nbsp; &nbsp;<i class='icon-calendar'>&nbsp;</i>&nbsp;".convertdate($date)."</div>
        </div>";
        $topics .= "<div class='right_cat'>
        <div class='face'>
            <img class='img_face' src='https://minotar.net/avatar/".getusername($creator)."/40.png'></div>
        <div class='comments_cat'>
            <div class='comments_top'>Comments</div>
            <div class='comments'>".topicreplies($cid, $tid)."</div></div>
        <div class='views_cat'>
            <div class='views_top'>Views</div>
            <div class='views'>".$views."</div></div>
        </div></li>";
    }
    echo $topics;
} else {
    echo "<div class='alert alert-danger text5'>There are no topics available yet.</div>";
}

?>
```

I have make the variable for you in the top.
Hope it work

Answer (score 0):

```
if (mysql_num_rows($res) > 0) {
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
        $tid = $row['id'];
        $cid = $row['category_id'];
        $title = $row['topic_title'];
        $views = $row['topic_views'];
        $date = $row['topic_date'];
        $creator = $row['topic_creator'];
        if ($row['topic_last_user']== "") { $last_user = getusername($row['topic_creator']); } else { $last_user = getusername($row['topic_last_user']); }
        if ($row['topic_last_user']== "") { $last2_user = 'Started by'; } else { $last2_user = 'Most recent by'; }
        $topics .= "<li class='category'><div class='left_cat'>
        <a class='underline' href='view_topic.php?cid=".$cid."&tid=".$tid."'><div class='title'><i class='icon-comment'></i>&nbsp;".$title."</div></a>
        <div class='info'><i class='icon-comments icon-1'></i>&nbsp;".topicreplies($cid, $tid)." Comments&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;<i class='icon-user icon-1'>
        &nbsp;</i>".$last2_user."&nbsp";
```

Syntax error is there at last line i.e  ".$last2_user." 
Just close the quote at "&nbsp";
This will solve your problem.

Comment: Okay so i did fixed that and added this `if ($info['rank'] == 1) {  echo "<div class='admin'>".$last_user."</div>"; } else { echo "<div>".$last_user."</div>"} ";` Then this is the error: **Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting ',' or ';' in C:\wamp\www\forum\index.php on line 157
**

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to insert an `if` statement inside the string you are creating. You can't do that as far as I know. However, the solution is easy. You end the string, insert your if statement, then append the rest of what you wanted. Like this:

```
if (mysql_num_rows($res) > 0) {
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) 
    {
    $tid = $row['id'];
    $cid = $row['category_id'];
    $title = $row['topic_title'];
    $views = $row['topic_views'];
    $date = $row['topic_date'];
    $creator = $row['topic_creator'];
    if ($row['topic_last_user']== "") 
        { $last_user = getusername($row['topic_creator']); } 
        else 
        { $last_user = getusername($row['topic_last_user']); }
    if ($row['topic_last_user']== "") 
        { $last2_user = 'Started by'; } 
        else 
        { $last2_user = 'Most recent by'; }
    $topics .= "<li class='category'><div class='left_cat'>
    <a class='underline' href='view_topic.php?cid=".$cid."&tid=".$tid."'>
    <div class='title'><i class='icon-comment'></i>&nbsp;".$title."</div></a>
    <div class='info'>
    <i class='icon-comments icon-1'></i>&nbsp;".topicreplies($cid, $tid)." 
    Comments&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;<i class='icon-user icon-1'>
    &nbsp;</i>".$last2_user."&nbsp";
    // The string above is ended - and you insert your if statement.
    // I changed the echo to an append to the string btw.

    if ($info['rank'] == 1) {  $topics .=  "<div class='admin'>".$last_user."</div>"; } else { $topics .=  "<div>".$last_user."</div>"; }

    // Now you get to continue appending to the string.

    $topics .= "&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;<i class='icon-calendar'>&nbsp;</i>&nbsp;".convertdate($date)."</div>
    </div>";
    $topics .= "<div class='right_cat'>
    <div class='face'>
        <img class='img_face' src='https://minotar.net/avatar/".getusername($creator)."/40.png'></div>
    <div class='comments_cat'>
        <div class='comments_top'>Comments</div>
        <div class='comments'>".topicreplies($cid, $tid)."</div></div>
    <div class='views_cat'>
        <div class='views_top'>Views</div>
        <div class='views'>".$views."</div></div>


    </div></li>";
    }
    echo $topics;
} else {
    echo "<div class='alert alert-danger text5'>There are no topics available yet.</div>";
}
```

Comment: Not sure I understand this comment. What else is going wrong?

Comment: I have a new problem can you see it at the top @Fluffeh

Answer (score 0):

The following code is what I have in the example provided above, and [Here](http://phpfiddle.org/api/run/35q-vvu)

```
<style type="text/css">
    .user { font-weight:900; color: #000; text-decoration: none !important; }
    .admin { font-weight:900; color: #F00; text-decoration: none !important; }
</style>

<form action="" method="POST">
    Input number and press enter: 
    </br>User = 0 Admin = 1</br>    
    <input name="rank" id="rank" type="text" />
</form>

<?php
    if (isset($_POST['rank'])) {
    $info['rank'] = $_POST['rank'];
    if($info['rank'] == 1) { $x= "<a class='admin'>Admin</a>"; } 
    else { $x= "<a class='user'>User</a>"; }
    echo $x;
   }
?>
```

As I mentioned in my comment above your code works fine, unless there is something going on elsewhere that we cant see with what you have given us.

And without a form.

```
<style type="text/css">
    .user { font-weight:900; color: #000; text-decoration: none !important; }
    .admin { font-weight:900; color: #F00; text-decoration: none !important; }
</style>

<?php
    $info['rank'] = 1;
    if($info['rank'] == 1) { $x= "<a class='admin'>Admin</a>"; }
    else { $x= "<a class='user'>User</a>"; }
    echo $x;
?>
```

Comment: @user2733334 Above is the code you requested, I hope it helps.